# When installing Android SDK 3.0 'adb kill-server' failed -- run manually if necessary. in Eclipse

Tags: android

When I try to install android sdk 3.0 i am getting error:

```
Preparing to install archives
Downloading Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 10
Installing Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 10
'adb kill-server' failed -- run manually if necessary.
```

Why? And when I tried to run android emulator - Eclipse stated that there is no `adb` file/process found. What seems to be a problem?

Comment: It might sound stupid but did you try rebooting (or killing all adb processes and restarting eclipse) before trying to install the sdk again?

Comment: Already tried, and this worked!

Comment: after rebooting my MacShit Pro, this message showed. Reboot again ? Eclipse is an ugly beast on the Mac

Comment: I opened a terminal and did it manually `/Android/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server`
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully * I don't know why Eclipse had a problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might sound stupid but try rebooting (or killing all adb processes and restarting eclipse) before trying to install the sdk again.